# EF Core FK not following convention can't be mapped

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My database table 'Book' doesn't follow the conventions of EF Core. The FK name isn't AuthorId but only Author.

So, this doesn't work:

```
public long? AuthorId { get; set; } = null;
public Author Author { get; set; }
```

Because EF Core doens't automatically match the table FK name.

So, I try this:

```
[ForeignKey("Author")]
public Author Author { get; set; }
[Column("Author")]
public long? AuthorId { get; set; } = null;
```

This still doesn't work, I get this exception:

> The property or navigation 'Author' cannot be added to the entity type 'Book' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Book'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the ForeignKey attribute with the "Author" entity name above the entity, put it above the ID, like this:

```
public Author Author { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Author")]
public long? AuthorId { get; set; } = null;
```

You are telling EF that the FK, `AuthorId`, goes with the entity named in the `[ForeignKey("Author")]` attribute. If you specify this way, you don't need the column attribute.

Comment: Alternatively, you can place the `ForeignKey` attribute on the `Author` property instead, like so `[ForeignKey("AuthorId")] public Author Author { get; set; }`